# How to show that limit is a delta function

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

Let $\{\phi_{n}(t)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a complete orthonormal system at $[a,b]$. Then
$$
   \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \phi_{n}(t)\phi_{n}(s) = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \phi_{n}(t)\phi_{n}(s) = \delta(t-s)
$$
How to show that
$$
  \lim\limits_{x \to +0} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \phi_{n}(t)\phi_{n}(s)e^{-a_{n}x} = \delta(t-s),
$$
in the sense that
$$
   \lim\limits_{x \to +0} \int \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \phi_{n}(t)\phi_{n}(s)e^{-a_{n}x} f(t) dt = f(s) 
$$
if series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \phi_n(t)\phi_n(s) e^{-a_n x}$ converge pointwise for $x > 0$ and where $a_{n} \to +\infty$.

Comment: If you ask mathematicians this question, you will have to say limit in what sense?  Some sort of distributions of two variables, I guess...

Comment: @GEdgar thank you for comment, I've improved my post

Answer (score 2):

Well (assuming real values)
$$
\int \phi_n(t) f(t) dt = u_n,
$$
say, are the coefficients for the orthogonal expansion of $f$ as $\sum_n u_n \phi_n(s) = f(s)$, where this holds in the sense of $L^2$ convergence.  Pointwise convergence fails in general.  Why should putting some funny exponential factors in there make it converge pointwise?

Comment: Exponential factor arises in study of heat equation. For general type of boundary conditions on segment Green function has the form $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)f_n(y) e^{-a_n t}$. For Dirichlet boundary conditions $f_n$-s are sinuses and exponent saves the day.